# Online histogram in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, histogram

I want to histogram an extremely large set of data. Since it won't fit in the memory, I'm using datastore to sequentially load chunks of data. It used to be easy to do this with the "hist" similar to:

```
data1 = randn(1,1000);
h = hist(data1,50);
data2 = randn(1,1000);
h = h + hist(data2,50);
```

Is there a way to do the same thing using the new "histogram" function as I would like to use some of the flexible features it offers. In other words, is there a way to perform online-histogram of data arriving in chunks just like we can do with calculating a cumulative running average of data samples for example.

Comment: You better use `histcounts` for that. And make sure the bins are the same for all chunks; use something like `histcounts(data2, edges)` rather then `histcounts(data2, M)`. Simply specifying the number of bins `M` may produce different edges in different chunks

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but this is no different than the method I listed. I'm looking for possible use of histogram function because I want to use some of the features such as change bin width, change normalization type...etc "after" all the data has been included in calculation and without having to load all the data in memory (simply because it not feasible).

Comment: `histogram` creates an object that actually contains the data, so it will not be possible. Ex: `hh=histogram(rand(10))`, `hh.Data` contains the random matrix.

Comment: @user2469430 How can you change bin width after all the data has been included in the calculation? I don't see how that could be done. You'd need the whole raw data for that

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. These are the same conclusions i reached so i thought it's worth it to seek new views on the topic.